# Android DP limit for guaranteed space

Tags: android, android-studio, screen-density

Sorry if this question has been asked before, in that case, it was hard to find it with a search but here we go:

When you use DP pixels in Android Studio, you will sometimes find that the elements become wider or shorter on a real device or emulator as compared to the preview. This makes sense, given different densities.

What I'm wondering is if there's a certain golden limit, in terms of height and/or width, that will guarantee that if you keep all the contents within this limit, nothing will be off-screen, no matter what the screen density of the device is.

For example, if I want to make a chess board, I want it to be as wide as possible, but to always fit on any screen. Is there a golden limit here?

Answer (score -1):

Don't use absolute values for that, as you never know how big the screen is. There are even Apps to choose the dp reported to the App.
Let's go with your example. You may have a View `Cell` for your chessboard.
You could then align them in a LinearLayout (`View` is used instead of `Cell`):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="8">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="8">

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/white" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/black" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/white" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/black" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/white" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/black" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/white" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/black" />

    </LinearLayout>

    ...
```

This would give the following result (In the example above I show only the first row):

[image: Sample image]

As you can see, the screen is used perfectly (Because `match_parent` is used in the root View), without using any absolute values. You can of course alter this to your specific needs, as you will likely want to put some more Views there.

Note: Don't do it like this in reality. I use nested weights in the example, which are bad for performance. This is just for you to get an idea of how to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but DP is not an absolute value, is it? It's relative to a 160 dpi screen. So, if I picture it correctly, there should be a certain limit (let's say, just making up a number, 800 dp in height, 300 dp in width) that ensures that it will fit inside any screen. 

Your solution will indeed work, but if weights are bad for performance, what's the better alternative?

Comment: What if the screen is smaller than that? That is very hypothetical, but there might exist devices like that (very low budget or smart watches). The problem is that you *don't know*.
Also using dp will not guarantee that the layout will look the same everywhere. That can be very confusing for the user. But sure, you can find a value which might look good, though not guaranteed to work on every screen.

Comment: Instead of a LinearLayout without nested weights you could use the PercentLayout available as a support library. Or build the layout dynamically just from code, by calculating the correct width and height for each Cell.
I recommend to write a custom view though, which does exactly what you want.

Comment: "What if the screen is smaller than that? "

The smaller a screen is relative to a 160 dpi screen, the fewer physical pixels will be translated from each dp in the code. Therefore, it only seems logical that there is a golden limit of dp that will fit for any width and for every height.

Comment: But this gets very abstract, so I might be wrong, maybe I'm packaging physical width with dpi somehow in this. Anyway, I'll try PercentLayout, that sounds perfect actually. And this is not bad for performance?

Comment: Just try to create a widget with lets say 120dp width. If you preview it in a phone and then in a tablet you will see the difference: Less of the screen is used.  

I haven't gone through the documentation extensively, but I think it should be better performance-wise.